# How to get isoFormat('LL') date with Carbon library but without year in the end?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I m using Carbon library in my laravel multilingual project

I want to display dates correctly formatted in the current locale, for example:

```
in 'en' => Thursday, January 5
in 'fr' => jeudi 5 janvier
```

What I m currently doing is this:

1- I get date using the isoFormat('LL') method which give me this : `January 5, 2017` (for 'en' locale)

2- remove the 5 last chars using substr

3- trim the extra semicolone

4 - add the day name at the beggining

5 - add a semicolone after day name (which is correct in english, but wrong in french)

So my question is: is it possible to get this format correctly with Carbon, and how?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

1- Add the next lines to class "AppServiceProvider.php"

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, config('app.locale'));
```

2-  use the next line to use format

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%A, %B  %d')
```

output en:

```
Tuesday, October 29
```

output fr:

```
mardi, octobre 29
```

If you want to change the order format use the next codes:

```
 $now = Carbon::now();
 $locale = App::getLocale();

 if (App::isLocale('en'))
    echo ($now->formatLocalized('%A, %B  %d')); // en Tuesday, October 29
 elseif(App::isLocale('fr'))
    echo ($now->formatLocalized('%A, %d %B')); // fr mardi, 29 octobre
```

simple notice

> [You also may know formatLocalized() method from Carbon 1. This method still works the same in Carbon 2 but you should better use isoFormat() instead.](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. this seems to be a good solution, but In my case I can't predict all the locales that the app will support. it will be better if Carbon could give the result correctly formatted by it self depending the current locale.

Comment: @ALnAc You are right if you working in many locales then it is so hard but you can use formatLocalized() in this case without change format and the string translate automatic